# Email Validation based on domain

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I want to know in COCOA, how can we validate email based on domain. For example, if i need that email address entered on text field should be from apple.com (ex: abc@apple.com) only, means if anyone enter gmail.com (ex : abc@gmail.com), so it should be invalid email address.

Thanks.

Comment: Validation of email addresses in general is a super thorny topic, and you'll find all sorts of info on SO. If you really literally need exact string matching against the @ sign and everything after, that's as Nikolai suggests.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *email;
if (! [[email lowercaseString] hasSuffix:@"apple.com"]) {
    // show error
}
```

Comment: May want to `[email lowercaseString]` before doing a compare here.

Answer (score 0):

Try a text entry field with a label next to it saying `@apple.com`